# TSQL List all the constituent bitwise integers within a larger integer

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, bitwise-operators

Firstly, apologies for not using the correct terminology here.  I don't actually know the correct terms, and thus have failed miserably to find a solution.  Please accept my example as the question, and I'll update the question accordingly if somebody can enlighten me (or delete and read the actual solution where it exists).

So far my research has only yielded comparisons of single bits within the whole, rather than showing *all*.

Given a set of integers:

```
ELEMENT   
-----------
Bricks    1
Plaster   2
Cement    4
Concrete  8
```

I have a result set that provides how these materials are used:

```
MIXTURE     ELEMENTS
----------------------
MixtureFoo  3
MixtureBar  7
MixtureBaz  11
```

I need to show the final set of mixtures, but with *each constituent element* listed that is used in the respective mixture:

```
MIXTURE     ELEMENTS   ELEMENT
------------------------------
MixtureFoo  3          1
MixtureFoo  3          2
MixtureBar  7          1
MixtureBar  7          2
MixtureBar  7          4
MixtureBaz  11         1
MixtureBaz  11         2
MixtureBaz  11         8
```

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't actually design this database, but if possible, consider changing the design to not use bitmasks. Aside from the obvious maintenance issues (can never have more than 64 parts, values need to be correctly constructed/deconstructed all the time), they are no picnic to query after either, as you've discovered (nor are such queries fast, typically). A proper intermediate table that links mixtures to elements admits natural joins (constraints like "an element may only occur once" can be added explicitly).

Comment: Yes, this question has been posted for *exactly* the reasons you specify.  Migration has begun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use bitwise operations:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
JOIN ELEMENT e
  ON t.ELEMENTS & e.w = e.w
ORDER BY MIXTURE, w;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b4ca2194cd28ee633f7c303be6b5e92a)**

Comment: Simply superb.  Thank you.